# Github pages/Jekyll Coldfusion redirect

Tags: coldfusion, jekyll, redirect, github-pages

I've just moved my Jekyll site to Github pages, however I realised that I have a couple of Coldfusion redirects - e.g. http://mysite/index.cfm?page=disclaimer.

These links are relied on from various locations on the web, is there anyway I can make it work? I have read up on Jekyll redirect-from plugin, however I have a feeling that wont work with this kind of link.
Any help?

Comment: If you can have Jekyll serve up the CFM file as plain HTML, you can change to content to use a meta-redirect tag or use JavaScript to redirect based on the query string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry but:

1. any `index.cfm` is returned as an `application/octet-stream` file so
   it's understood as a file to be downloaded.
2. any [url query string](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string) like `toto.html?q=myQuery` will be totally
   ignored by your static site. Query string is supposed to be
   interpreted server side, so any query string after `toto.htm` will 
   always return `toto.html` itself with no interaction from server side

Comment: Ah I see, I had a feeling it wouldn't be possible, thanks anyway.